# How to integrate SimpleITK in Unity for app in HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cross-compiling, hololens, simpleitk

I'm developing an app in Unity 2020.3.3f1 to be deployed in HoloLens 2. This app has to deal with medical images thus I need to use SimpleITK library.
I've downloaded SimpleITK source files and compiled them in Visual Studio 2017 for ARM64 architecture in order to match HoloLens 2 ARM64 architecture, following this procedure: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/11/15/official-support-for-windows-10-on-arm-development/.
I've added the native and managed .dll in Asset folder of the Unity project and I've written a c# script in which I use SimpleITK.

Everything works correctly in the Unity Editor without errors, but when I deploy the app in HoloLens 2 nothing works.
Launching the debug of the solution in Visual Studio (Debug -> Start Debugging), these lines appear in the output window as soon as the script which uses SimpleITK is called:

```
'SpatialAwareness.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\USERS\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\BaseVS.Release_ARM64.Elena\SimpleITKCSharpNative.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'SpatialAwareness.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'U:\USERS\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\BaseVS.Release_ARM64.Elena\SimpleITKCSharpNative.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC1AAF39EC in SpatialAwareness.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x00000094365FE590.
```

How can the error be resolved?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the SimpleITK DLL you built is missing the Windows runtime component.

If you created your C++ DLL as a Win32 binary, it would throw exceptions when running on the HoloLens2 because Unity will not include standard Win32 binaries when it builds a WSA project. Therefore, you need to recreate the Win32 DLL as a UWP DLL or port the native win32 DLL to the UWP DLL, see the guidance here: [To port a native DLL to the UWP without creating a new project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160#to-port-a-native-dll-to-the-uwp-without-creating-a-new-project)